# Looking for an existing lightweight RF protocol

Tags: arduino-yun, rf

I'm currently looking for an RF protocol that doesn't use much power (generally much less than wifi) Something similar to simple AM radio, but with an authentication library readily available. ZigBee has about 250kbps bandwidth. I don't need nearly as much, so something with ~5kbps (dial-up speeds) would be acceptable. Using the Arduino Yun; so i'm constrained to the 5V output.
I'm also trying to stay away from the 2.4 GHz band.

Is there anything out there with this in mind? I was thinking maybe [Z-Wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-Wave)?

As far as the ZWave chips go this is where i'm at: http://pastebin.com/B0Yif3LS

Comment: Have a look at http://www.anarduino.com/miniwireless/ or http://lowpowerlab.com/blog/category/moteino/ or even http://jeelabs.org/.